# How to retrieve records from two objects which has lookup relationship?

Tags: soql, lookup, query, map, wrapper-class

I have Custom object **DriverEfficiency__c** which has (**contact**(lookup),Car_Meter_Reading__c,Efficiency_Rating__c,Fuel_Liter__c) fields.

The Problem is I need to create a Vf Page to retrieve records from **contact** and **DriverEfficiency__c**..

I used **Wrapper Class** to retrieve records from different objects.But I got the unrelated result.**Contact** field displays unrelated records for **DriverEfficiency__c**.

I need related contact records for the **DriverEfficiency__c**.(which has contact lookup)

Comment: is ur requirement to show all the contacts and its linked driver efficiency records ? or only for a certain set of contacts ?

Comment: Yes.My requirement to show all the contacts and its linked driver efficiency records in Vf page.I am getting unlinked contacts from the above code.I need exact contacts linked with driver efficiency..Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You can try solving your problem using relationship queries.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

For now you can try this query

```
[select Car_Meter_Reading__c,Efficiency_Rating__c,Fuel_Liter__c, Contact__r.name,Contact__r.Phone from DriverEfficiency__c  ]
```

Comment: I tried this code in Developer Console it shows following error.                                                           Efficiency_Rating__c,Fuel_Liter__c, Contact.name,Contact.Phone from
                                    ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:65
Didn't understand relationship 'Contact' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: sorry my bad.. append __r after contact, i have edited the query you can try this code now

Comment: Sorry.It is showing same error.....Didn't understand relationship 'Contact__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Here "Contact__r" represent your Relationship name.  Go to your DriverEfficiency object fields -> Open Lookup(contact) type field  ----> In that scroll down and see "Relationship Name" --------- You need to use that name by concatinating  "__r"  . 

for exmaple : Relationship name = DriverContact  ----> then use ---- DriverContact__r.Phone, DriverContact__r.Name

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to your custom object, then go to the lookup field.
2. Select 'Field Name' value (Assume you have 'Contact_ABC'). Note : Do not use API Name or relationship name.
3. suffix __r to it. That will give you relationship name and you can use it to query any field
   Example : 
   Contact_ABC__r.id - This will give you contact ID
   Contact_ABC__r.name - This will give you contact Name

Comment: This approach will not always work. For example, if there is a namespace.